# Is this a transimpedance amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transimpedance

Help needed on the below image: is this considered a transimpedance amplifier?

With the V<sub>o</sub> of 3 V given, can I find out the current source current? Since this current source from 0:255 μA (2<sup>8</sup> bits), can I convert this to the DAC value?

This is how I calculate it; is this correct?

I<sub>in</sub> = (1.25V-0V/4.22K) + (1.25V-3V/10K) = 121 μA

Does that mean, if convert to DAC, when DAC = 121 μA, my V<sub>o</sub> will be at 3 V?

[image]

Comment: The 4.22k resistor turns the current input into a voltage, which then feeds a normal inverting voltage amplifier.  In a transimpedance amplifier the 4.22k resistor is absent, and current is driven through the feedback resistor.

Comment: Hey Bill, this is *exactly* the same image as https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/614789/op-amp-dac-with-current-source , so you and Raymond are the same person. Please don't open new accounts when you already have one!

Comment: (matter of fact, you should probably have modified that question instead of asking a new one!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that calculation is correct. The output will be ~4.21 V at 0 uA, and change at a rate of -10 mV/uA.

The voltage for 0uA is calculated by the gain times 1.25 V.
$$Vout = 1.25~V*(1+10000/4220) = 4.212085~V$$

The slope is determined by the feedback resistor and the polarity is inverted, for example if you made it 20K the slope would be -20000:1 or -20 mV/uA